# How to convert an integer to a String without buildin Java methods?

Tags: java, algorithm, casting

I'm getting ready for an interview and came across this question:

> Write an algorithm that converts integer to String without using
> ready-made implementations?

We can extract single numbers using modulo and then use type casting in concatenation (java) like below:

```java
        int inputNumber = 145;
        int modifiedNumber = inputNumber;
        String convertedNumber = "";
        int lastDigit;

        while (modifiedNumber != 0) {
            lastDigit = modifiedNumber % 10;
            convertedNumber = lastDigit + convertedNumber ;
            modifiedNumber /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println("Converted number is: " + convertedNumber);
```

**Question:** How to convert a single number to a string, but **without** using implicit typecast of concatenating the number onto the string? Is it possible in Java language?

Comment: Where is there typecasting here? You mean the implicit typecast of concatenating the number onto the string? Would it be considered typecasting to use the digit as a way to create the character (ASCII) value of the number? (That's a potential hint.)

Comment: Yes, i mean implicit typecast  when using concatenating the number onto the string. I suppose that using character may be good solution.

Comment: Thought about adding `switch case` for converting (with ASCII or just strings), but it seems not pretty solution.

Comment: Characters are numeric values, e.g., 65 is A. So if you know you have an integer you can use that as an offset to find the related ASCII value, e.g., `'A' + 5 == 'E'`. No switch should be necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid any numeric to String type conversion, and you're not allowed to use built in functions, I think the options would be a switch statement or an array.

```
String[] digits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

int inputNumber=1234;
String convertedNumber = "";
for(int n=inputNumber; n>0; n/=10)
    convertedNumber = digits[n % 10] + convertedNumber;
System.out.println(convertedNumber);
```

Comment: I think this is it, a simple solution without using buildin tools. Little weird question but that it is. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
int inputNumber=1234;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");
sb.append(inputNumber);
String strI = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I thought about StringBuilder but it is the same, implicit typecast solution.

Comment: So is that a problem ?

Comment: The question is how to avoid implicit typecast, not how to make it in other way.

Comment: And not using built-in Java functionality (within reason)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would change about the OP's code is to use a StringBuilder instead of doing all that repeated concatenation.

```
public String convert(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return "0";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int zero = (int)'0';
    while (n > 0) {
        sb.insert(0, (char)(zero + (n % 10)));
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


@Test
public void testConvert() {
    assertEquals("123", convert(123));
    assertEquals("1230", convert(1230));
    assertEquals("12301", convert(12301));
    assertEquals("1230123", convert(1230123));
    assertEquals("0", convert(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```java
        int myNumber1 = 125;
        int myNumber2 = 265;
        int myNumber3 = 563;

        String numberAsString1 = myNumber1 + "";
        String numberAsString2 = String.valueOf(myNumber2);
        String numberAsString3 = ((Integer) myNumber3 ).toString();
```

Comment: String 1 has the same implicit typecasting, 3 has *explicit* typecasting, 2 and 3 use built-in Java methods, which the OP is explicitly trying to avoid :)